# C++ filesystem iterator Invalid Argument

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems

I'm using the `fs::recursive_directory_iterator` to list all the files from a drive.

I'm also passing `fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied` to prevent the iterator to throw when trying to go inside non-allowed directories. So there shouldn't be any problem…

But when trying to iterate inside special directories (Volume Information, Recycle.Bin,…):

```
filesystem error: cannot increment recursive directory iterator: Invalid argument
```

I have to try…catch the iteration as a workaround, but why do I have this issue ? How should I fix this ?

I can reproduce it with the minimal example from cppreference.com:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    for(auto& p: fs::recursive_directory_iterator("M:", fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied))
        std::cout << p << '\n';
}
```

Result:

```
… (Listing real files)

"M:\\System Volume Information"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot increment recursive directory iterator: Invalid argument
```

EDIT: Also, the filesystem_error methods path1(), path2() return empty paths. Is it a gcc bug ?

Comment: `skip_permission_denied` is not available as on option in Visual Studio version of `filesystem`. So this looks a gcc/Windows bug. `"System Volume Information"` is protected, you can't read it even with admin access, unless you change the folder settings with admin access, which is not recommended.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - not need change folder access. enough enable `SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE` in token (if we have it) and use `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` in `CreateFile` call if we want read only access. if need write access too - need `SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE` also to be enabled

Comment: and you need use not `<experimental/filesystem>` but `<filesystem>` header. and `fs = std::filesystem`. the `skip_permission_denied` defined only here. simply look in header files

Comment: I got stuck with this too. [filesystem::filesystem_error issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988629/c-stdfilesystemfilesystem-error-exception-trying-to-read-system-volume-inf).  I solved my problem for the moment by using Boost instead of the standard C++ library std::filesystem.  Boost implements it, so you can swap out <filesystem> for <boost/filesystem> and link in the filesystem library from Boost instead.  Works well for me.

Comment: The issue still persists in GCC 12.1.0...

Answer (score 4):

if simply search `skip_permission_denied` symbol in header files easy can view that this symbol exist only in `<filesystem>` but not in `<experimental/filesystem>`. you include wrong header file.

and we need use `namespace fs = std::filesystem;` - without `experimental` term.

about file permissions - if caller have [`SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_se_exports) :

> This privilege allows the user to circumvent file and directory
>   permissions to back up the system. This privilege causes the system to
>   grant all read access control to any file, regardless of the access
>   control list (ACL) specified for the file. Any access request other
>   than read is still evaluated with the ACL. The following access rights
>   are granted if this privilege is held:
>
> - `READ_CONTROL`
> - `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY`
> - `FILE_GENERIC_READ`
> - `FILE_TRAVERSE`
>
> User-mode applications represent this privilege as the following
>   user-right string: "Back up files and directories".

also we need use `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT` in [`NtCreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntcreatefile) or [`NtOpenFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntopenfile) call. or `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` in [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew).

when we use `recursive_directory_iterator` we not control this point (not direct open folder yourself). however in current implementation this class call `FindFirstFileExW` function for iterate. this api internal call [`NtOpenFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntopenfile) always with `FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT` option. as result `SeBackupPrivilege`working here. we need enable `SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE` in thread or process token, of course if we have this privilege in token:

```
#define LAA(se) {{se},SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED|SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT}

#define BEGIN_PRIVILEGES(tp, n) static const struct {ULONG PrivilegeCount;LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges[n];} tp = {n,{
#define END_PRIVILEGES }};

// in case you not include wdm.h, where this defined
#define SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE (17L)

ULONG AdjustPrivileges()
{
    if (ImpersonateSelf(SecurityImpersonation))
    {
        HANDLE hToken;
        if (OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, TRUE, &hToken))
        {
            BEGIN_PRIVILEGES(tp, 1)
                LAA(SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE),
            END_PRIVILEGES
            AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)&tp, 0, 0, 0);
            CloseHandle(hToken);
        }
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```

final code can look like:

```
#include <filesystem>

void demo()
{
    AdjustPrivileges();

    fs::recursive_directory_iterator item(L"c:\\System Volume Information", 
        fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied), end;

    while (item != end)
    {
        DbgPrint("%S\n", item->path().c_str());
        item++;
    }
}
```

Comment: <experimental/filesystem> has skip_permission_denied. I don't know which compiler you use.
Also, I don't want my soft to have more permissions than already allowed, I just wanted the permission denied to be reported as such.

Comment: @Salamandar - may be we of course look for different versions of `experimental/filesystem` file, but in my version - no such symbol [`skip_permission_denied`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_options) - in this file. but it exist in `filesystem` header. are you include it instead `experimental/filesystem` ? and how compiler here related at all ?