# C++ Can`t iterate through C drive

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, c++17, filesystems

My task is to find a file by its name. Search has to be started from C:\ drive. As I was testing my functions on other drives like D:\ or A:\ everything was all right, but I am trying to do it with C:\ drive it doesn`t work
I am using , g++ compiler, C++ 17, Windows OS.
Calling function in main.cpp

```
 try {
        if (SearchFile::find_file(fs::path("C:\\"), fileName)) {
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (const fs::filesystem_error& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error accessing filesystem: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Exception path1: " << e.path1() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Exception path2: " << e.path2() << std::endl;
    }
    for(const auto& drive : drives){
        fs::path drivePath(drive);
        std::string driveLetter = drivePath.string().substr(0, 1);
        if (!(driveLetter == "C" || driveLetter == "c")) {
            if (SearchFile::find_file(drivePath, fileName)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

My functions, which located in SearchFile class

```
void SearchFile::search_in_directory(const fs::path &drive, const std::string &fileName,
                                     std::atomic<bool> &foundFile, std::mutex &mutex) {
    try {

    for(const auto& file_iterator : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(drive,
                                                                     fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)){
            if(foundFile) return;
            if(file_iterator.is_regular_file() && file_iterator.path().filename() == fileName){
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                std::cout << file_iterator.path() << std::endl;
                foundFile = true;
                return;
            }

    }
    } catch (const fs::filesystem_error& e) {
        // Print the exception details for debugging
        std::cerr << drive.filename() << '\n';
        std::cerr << "File system exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Exception path1: " << e.path1() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Exception path2: " << e.path2() << std::endl;
    }
}
bool SearchFile::find_file(const std::filesystem::path &drive, const std::string &fileName) {
       adjust_priviledges();
    std::atomic<bool> found = false;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::mutex mutex;

    try {
        for(const auto& file_iterator :
                fs::recursive_directory_iterator(drive, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)){
            if (fs::is_symlink(file_iterator)) {
                continue;
            }
            if(found) break;
            if(fs::is_directory(file_iterator ) && threads.size() < MAX_THREADS ){

                threads.emplace_back(&search_in_directory, file_iterator.path(),
                                     fileName, std::ref(found), std::ref(mutex));

            } else if(file_iterator.is_regular_file() && file_iterator.path().filename() == fileName){
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                std::cout << file_iterator.path() << std::endl;
                found = true;
                break;
            }}
    } catch (const fs::filesystem_error& e) {

        std::cerr << "File system exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Exception path1111: " << e.path1() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Exception path2: " << e.path2() << std::endl;
    }

    for(auto& thread : threads){
        thread.join();
    }
    return found;
}
```

Most of the time I have this : "File system exception: filesystem error: cannot increment recursive directory iterator: Invalid argument" while trying to run my program.
Also I was trying to [AdjustPriviledges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799541/c-filesystem-iterator-invalid-argument), but still it doesn`t solve the problem.
In addition I have tried to run it as an Administrator and disabled Windows defender, still no results.

Comment: Your `for` loop aborts on the first exception. Don't you really want to put the try/catch block inside the for instead of around it?

Comment: Assuming you're scanning the system drive there's going to be a good sized chunk you're not going to have access to, even if you run the program elevated. Since you know there will likely be errors you'll need to log or ignore them and continue.

Comment: An accurate description of all this multi-threaded logic comes from Scotty's "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to clog up the drain" quote from Star Trek III. First, I would implement the needed functionality as a straightforward, ordinary chunk of code. Only then, after everything's working, I would consider dividing the work between multiple execution threads, if performance warranted. The shown code appears to spawn a thread for every directory. A typical Windows drive will have thousands of directories. A few thousand `std::thread`s in MS-Windows always ends in tears.

Answer (score 4):

There's an argument here for using Windows' (platform specific) [`FindFirstFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfileexw) and [`FindNextFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew) functions.

- You can use the Unicode variants of these functions (I wouldn't like to say whether the standard library does or not).
- You can use the magic `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` flag, which speeds things up *a lot*.
- You can pass the `FindExInfoBasic` flag, which speeds things up some more.
- You get back a [`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-win32_find_dataw) structure for each file found, which contains quite a bit of useful info (including the name, ofc).
- There are various ways you can tell Windows what matches you want returned, which might come in handy.
- You have more control over what you do when an error occurs (typically `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`).
- On Windows 10, you can handle paths longer than `MAX_PATH` (260) characters, although that's unlikely to be necessary on your system drive.

So, give it some thought.  It's not difficult, but you might prefer your code to be portable.  And as others have said, get rid of all those threads.  That magic flag should give you call the performance you need.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspicious:

```
threads.emplace_back(&search_in_directory, file_iterator.path(),
                                     fileName, std::ref(found),std::ref(mutex));
```

`file_iterator.path()` returns a reference to a path instance with a lifetime no longer than the lifetime of the file_iterator itself.  And it's getting passed to `search_in_directory` in another thread via reference.  The path instance could be deleted before the thread even starts.

Let's make copies of the path and strings with guaranteed lifetime before passing by reference.  We can pass `found` an `mutex` as references

Do this:

```
auto path = file_iterator.path();
// capture path and FileName by value (make a copy)
// capture found and mutex by reference
std::thread t = [path, fileName, &found, &mutex] () {
   search_in_directory(path, fileName, found, mutex);
};
threads.push_back(std::move(t));
```

I'm not sure if that's the only issue, but it certainly seems like a problem.